# Vertical tab control with horizontal text at design time

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

A clear omission seems to be that after applying this approach:

- [Vertical Tab Control with horizontal text in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498413/vertical-tab-control-with-horizontal-text-in-winforms)

Which is also recommended by Microsoft:

- [How to: Display Side-Aligned Tabs with TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms404305%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

There is no text on tabs at design time, so further development and support becomes a nightmare.

[image]

Is there a way to make tab text also display at design time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create your own control so the custom drawing also works at design time.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form.  I tweaked it a bit to make it no so garish.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class VerticalTabControl : TabControl {
    public VerticalTabControl() {
        this.Alignment = TabAlignment.Right;
        this.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
        this.ItemSize = new Size(this.Font.Height * 3 / 2, 75);
    }
    public override Font Font {
        get { return base.Font;  }
        set {
            base.Font = value;
            this.ItemSize = new Size(value.Height * 3 / 2, base.ItemSize.Height);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        using (var _textBrush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor)) {
            TabPage _tabPage = this.TabPages[e.Index];
            Rectangle _tabBounds = this.GetTabRect(e.Index);

            if (e.State != DrawItemState.Selected) e.DrawBackground();
            else {
                using (var brush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.Bounds, Color.White, Color.LightGray, 90f)) {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
                }
            }

            StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
            _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, this.Font, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you use `Font.Height * 3 / 2` to adjust the height of the `ItemSize` property? I thought using [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better way.

Comment: Not particularly, it is just there to leave enough margin in the tab.  Pick anything you want.

Comment: Alright. My curiousity has been satisfied now. In my implementation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27171218/117870) I used the height from `TextRenderer.MeasureText` and then added the `Padding.Y` value. I did that because it makes my custom control consistent with the standard `TabControl`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to subclass the `TabControl` and override `OnDrawItem`. Here's an example:

```
Public Class UITabControl
    Inherits TabControl

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        Using brush As New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
            Using format As New StringFormat() With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center}
                Select Case Me.Alignment
                    Case TabAlignment.Left
                        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
                    Case TabAlignment.Top
                        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
                End Select
                format.FormatFlags = (format.FormatFlags Or StringFormatFlags.NoWrap)
                Dim rect As Rectangle = e.Bounds
                rect.X += 3
                rect.Width -= 6
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.TabPages(e.Index).Text, Me.Font, brush, rect, format)
            End Using
        End Using
        MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: +1. Though I like @HansPassant's solution better, the gradient rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you linked to my question, I thought it expedient to inform you of updates to my question thread.

I have, in an [answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27171218/117870), uploaded my code for the control in the interest of the programming community.

This is a screenshot of the control at runtime.
[image: Vertical Tabs Control screenshot]

It features full design time support, automatic resizing of tabs (up to 128px wide) and tab icons as well.

The code can be downloaded from [here](http://ge.tt/2COX9iS/v/2?c).

Comment: Thanks. It could be helpful for other developers if you outlined basic properties of your custom control, and why it should be used, maybe add some code to your answer. Otherwise looks like an ad (even though product is free). Please note that publishing code on a file share is not reliable. It's best to create an open source project (for example, on GitHub), this way people can expand on your creation, and it won't be lost 2 years from now.