# C# vertical tab control with horizontal text

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display some information in tab control [This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ5Sg.png).

I have used the methods that I found on your side to make changes in properties of tab control and using Draw Event but the output is not like what i needed.The output comes like[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs278.png)..
I want the text to be horizontal. Also my VS is 2008

Comment: please add what UI framework you are using. Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: I am using Windows Forms Application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical Tab Control with horizontal text in Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498413/vertical-tab-control-with-horizontal-text-in-winforms)

Answer (score 14):

I followed these [instructions in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498413/vertical-tab-control-with-horizontal-text-in-winforms) and converted them to C#. Worked for me. Basically in tab control properties set the following:

1. Alignment = Left
2. SizeMode = Fixed
3. ItemSize = 30, 120: Width = 30 Height = 120
4. DrawMode = OwnerDrawFixed

Then you have to handle `DrawItem` event like that:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    var text = this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
    var sizeText = g.MeasureString(text, this.tabControl1.Font);

    var x = e.Bounds.Left + 3;
    var y = e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sizeText.Height) / 2;

    g.DrawString(text, this.tabControl1.Font, Brushes.Black, x, y);
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the SizeMode property to Fixed, so that all tabs are the same width.
 Set the ItemSize property to the preferred fixed size for the tabs. Keep in mind that the ItemSize property behaves as though the tabs were on top, although they are left-aligned. As a result, in order to make the tabs wider, you must change the Height property, and in order to make them taller, you must change the Width property. [I set the ItemSize as: 25, 150].

Set the DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed.

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
```

{

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

Brush _textBrush;



// Get the item from the collection.

TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];



// Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.

Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);



if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)

{



    // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.

    _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);

}

else

{

    _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);

    e.DrawBackground();

}



// Use our own font.

Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", (float)10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);



// Draw string. Center the text.

StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();

_stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

_stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
```

}

Comment: Thanks... mistake which I did was didn`t set the ItemSize.