# How do I add images to a vertical TabControl?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vertical-alignment, tabcontrol

So I've been browsing around and experimenting on how to make a vertical TabControl. I found a few posts and managed to get it done but then I stumbled upon another issue. How do I add images to the various tabs?

Comment: You need to draw them yourself... Or if your tabs are usercontrols you can add imageboxs to them... Also without posting what you have tried will get the question closed real quick, IMO update us with what you have tried and where you are stuck at.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is what I came across. The solution at the bottom of the post is what I want to scrap and use to add the image but I don't quite understand it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498413/vertical-tab-control-with-horizontal-text-in-winforms

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add images to a tab control you can do something like that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps, if anything else feel free to ask.

Comment: Haha :D excellent! That worked! Thank you. I can finally move on from this roadblock

Comment: glad to help, if this was the answer you were looking for kindly vote up thx.

Comment: My reputation is low. Its recorded but it won't show.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include a text-only description of these steps too, in case the image links break or if somebody doesn't feel like squinting.