# Winforms .net 4.7.2 simple custom control hangs VS 2019 designer

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

vb.net 4.7.2 Winforms, VS 2019 Pro latest patch.

I created a subclass of Winforms Tab Control using code I found here ( [Vertical Tab Control with horizontal text in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498413/vertical-tab-control-with-horizontal-text-in-winforms) ) and adapted it (to clean up memory leaks).  While it works as expected when empty in the designer, creating some nested TableLayoutPanels on a couple of tabs and filling them with controls, using dock fill, causes VS 2019 to wait interminably.

I have isolated it to the paint event handler by trying to add a flag to keep it from recursing; that solved the hang but nothing would draw in the designer.  So, to answer a question in the comments, it appears that paint may be being called repeatedly.  But I see nothing offensive in the paint method that would take a long time nor anything that would recurse.

The code for the control is below.  Any ideas?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

''' <summary>
''' Tab Control with "tabs" vertically stacked on the left.
''' </summary>
Public Class DotNetBarTabControl
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

''' <summary>
''' Is there a border?  True if yea.
''' </summary>
Private _bBorder As Boolean = False

''' <summary>
''' Control property that shows true if there is a border.
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Property Border As Boolean
    Get
        Return _bBorder
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _bBorder = value
    End Set
End Property

''' <summary>
''' Constructor.
''' </summary>
Sub New()
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint Or ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw Or ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
    DoubleBuffered = True
    SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
    ItemSize = New Size(44, 136)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Override of the CreateHandle Event Handler.
''' </summary>
Protected Overrides Sub CreateHandle()
    MyBase.CreateHandle()
    Alignment = TabAlignment.Left
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Override of the paint routine, to paint the control.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="e">Painting Event Arguments.</param>
''' <remarks>
''' 2023-03-10 JFT: Add invocation of mybase.paint to remedy hang issue in designer.
''' 2023-03-07 JFT: Implement USING statements to remedy significant memory leaks in the 
'''                 original StackOverflow-obtained code.  Tests showed that memory leaks
'''                 were reduced to zero.
''' </remarks>
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    Using B As New Bitmap(Width, Height)
        Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
            Try : SelectedTab.BackColor = Color.White : Catch : End Try
            G.Clear(Color.White)
            Using SB As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(246, 248, 252))
                G.FillRectangle(SB, New Rectangle(0, 0, ItemSize.Height + 4, Height))
                Using P_170_187_204 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(170, 187, 204))
                    If _bBorder Then
                        G.DrawLine(P_170_187_204, New Point(Width - 1, 0), New Point(Width - 1, Height - 1))    'comment out to get rid of the borders
                        G.DrawLine(P_170_187_204, New Point(ItemSize.Height + 1, 0), New Point(Width - 1, 0))                   'comment out to get rid of the borders
                        G.DrawLine(P_170_187_204, New Point(ItemSize.Height + 3, Height - 1), New Point(Width - 1, Height - 1)) 'comment out to get rid of the borders
                    End If
                    G.DrawLine(P_170_187_204, New Point(ItemSize.Height + 3, 0), New Point(ItemSize.Height + 3, 999))
                    For i As Integer = 0 To TabCount - 1
                        If i = SelectedIndex Then
                            Dim x2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(GetTabRect(i).Location.X - 2, GetTabRect(i).Location.Y - 2), New Size(GetTabRect(i).Width + 3, GetTabRect(i).Height - 1))
                            Dim myBlend As New ColorBlend()
                            myBlend.Colors = {Color.FromArgb(232, 232, 240), Color.FromArgb(232, 232, 240), Color.FromArgb(232, 232, 240)}
                            myBlend.Positions = {0.0F, 0.5F, 1.0F}
                            Using lgBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(x2, Color.Black, Color.Black, 90.0F)
                                lgBrush.InterpolationColors = myBlend
                                G.FillRectangle(lgBrush, x2)
                            End Using '  lgBrush As New LinearGradientBrush(x2, Color.Black, Color.Black, 90.0F)
                            G.DrawRectangle(P_170_187_204, x2)
                            G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                            Dim p() As Point = {New Point(ItemSize.Height - 3, GetTabRect(i).Location.Y + 20), New Point(ItemSize.Height + 4, GetTabRect(i).Location.Y + 14), New Point(ItemSize.Height + 4, GetTabRect(i).Location.Y + 27)}
                            G.FillPolygon(Brushes.White, p)
                            G.DrawPolygon(P_170_187_204, p)
                            Using fBold As New Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                                Using sfCenterCenter As New StringFormat With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center}
                                    If ImageList IsNot Nothing Then
                                        Try
                                            If ImageList.Images(TabPages(i).ImageIndex) IsNot Nothing Then
                                                G.DrawImage(ImageList.Images(TabPages(i).ImageIndex), New Point(x2.Location.X + 8, x2.Location.Y + 6))
                                                G.DrawString("      " & TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.DimGray, x2, sfCenterCenter)
                                                G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, fBold, Brushes.DimGray, x2, sfCenterCenter)
                                            Else
                                                G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, fBold, Brushes.DimGray, x2, sfCenterCenter)
                                            End If
                                        Catch ex As Exception
                                            G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, fBold, Brushes.DimGray, x2, sfCenterCenter)
                                        End Try
                                    Else
                                        G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, fBold, Brushes.DimGray, x2, sfCenterCenter)
                                    End If
                                End Using ' sfCenterCenter As New StringFormat 
                            End Using ' fBold As New Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                            Using P_200_200_250 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 250))
                                G.DrawLine(P_200_200_250, New Point(x2.Location.X - 1, x2.Location.Y - 1), New Point(x2.Location.X, x2.Location.Y))
                                G.DrawLine(P_200_200_250, New Point(x2.Location.X - 1, x2.Bottom - 1), New Point(x2.Location.X, x2.Bottom))
                            End Using ' P_200_200_250 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 250))
                        Else
                            Dim x2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(GetTabRect(i).Location.X - 2, GetTabRect(i).Location.Y - 2), New Size(GetTabRect(i).Width + 3, GetTabRect(i).Height + 1))
                            G.FillRectangle(SB, x2)
                            G.DrawLine(P_170_187_204, New Point(x2.Right, x2.Top), New Point(x2.Right, x2.Bottom))
                            If ImageList IsNot Nothing Then
                                Try
                                    If ImageList.Images(TabPages(i).ImageIndex) IsNot Nothing Then
                                        G.DrawImage(ImageList.Images(TabPages(i).ImageIndex), New Point(x2.Location.X + 8, x2.Location.Y + 6))
                                        G.DrawString("      " & TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.DimGray, x2, New StringFormat With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
                                    Else
                                        G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.DimGray, x2, New StringFormat With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
                                    End If
                                Catch ex As Exception
                                    G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.DimGray, x2, New StringFormat With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
                                End Try
                            Else
                                G.DrawString(TabPages(i).Text, Font, Brushes.DimGray, x2, New StringFormat With {.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End Using ' P_170_187_204 As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(170, 187, 204))
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(CType(B.Clone, Bitmap), 0, 0)
            End Using ' SB as new SolidBrush
        End Using ' Graphics.FromImage(B)
    End Using ' B as new bitmap
    GC.Collect() ' clean up memory freed from Using blocks
End Sub

End Class
```

I'd add the code for the designer of a window using the control but I think that adding 1000+ lines of designer code would make this way too long.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/walkthrough-debugging-custom-windows-forms-controls-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: When you say that you've isolated it to the `OnPaint` method, what does that mean exactly? Does the method get called repeatedly? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: As requested, source URL and answers to other questions provided.  Thanks for asking for the additional info; I was a bit flustered before posting and should have added the same before posting initially.

Comment: @Hans Passant -- I went ahead and set up the debug and set the breakpoint on the mybase.OnPaint, and it broke on OnPaint hundreds of times when I did the change to a different tab. The call stack appeared to point to recursion, but I see nothing in the code that would cause it.

Comment: Delete the `GC.Collect()`. Why did you add it?

Comment: Trying that now.  Added it in order to clear up the memory that was consumed in the paint method.

Comment: Not running GC. Collect() Did not speed things up tremendously; it still hangs and repeatedly paints if I click on the property editor ">" icon in the upper right of the TableLayout panel on the tab or if I press F4 for the property editor.  To duplicate lay this control on a windows form, add 7-8 tabs, and put a TLP on the form and add 5-6 rows.  Best to set dock to Fill.

Comment: Nothing in the posted code calls the `OnPaint` method repeatedly unless you're hiding some relevant code. Use your debugger to step over/out (F10/Shift+F11) to find the caller. This code needs a serious optimization anyway.

Comment: @dr.null -- I will look to see what the code that repeatedly calls onPaint is.  It looks to be part of TableLayoutPanel from the call stack.  What optimizations do you see?  The only thing I see is that I could create the regular and bold fonts on first paint and use those objects until dispose, and perhaps the brushes as well.

Comment: You need to rewrite the whole thing but first solve the main problem. Try something for me just in case you have controls with transparent back colors. Don't create a device context from a Bitmap. Comment the `Using B ..` and `Using G ...` along with `e.Graphics.DrawImage(CType(B.Clone...`. At the first line, assign the graphics object to a local variable `G` to not change much in the code: `Dim G = e.Graphics`. See how it goes.

Comment: I just found the root cause of this problem!
          Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
            Try : SelectedTab.BackColor = Color.White : Catch : End Try
            G.Clear(Color.White) 

If I place the try into an if statement "if SelectedTab.Backcolor <> Color.White" that solves the whole thing.  It was repeatedly trying to paint something that had not changes.

I will try to speed it up more by not using a separate graphics.  Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of that `try .. catch` block and setting the BackColor parts. Instead, override the `OnControlAdded` method and write: `If TypeOf e.Control Is TabPage Then e.Control.BackColor = Color.White`.

Comment: I think that the original author put that in there because he was generating -- no pun intended -- stack overflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved.

The code in the paint method:

```
        Try : SelectedTab.BackColor = Color.White : Catch : End Try
```

Was causing recursion.

Placing it in an IF statement:

```
    if SelectedTab.BackColor <> Color.White then
        Try : SelectedTab.BackColor = Color.White : Catch : End Try
    End If
```

solved the recursion that caused the issue, because if we assigned the color it would immediately issue a recursive paint call.

Still cleaning up things to make the code good and leak-free.  Thanks for all of the excellent suggestions.

Comment: _Still cleaning up things to make the code good and leak-free._ [Try this version](https://pastebin.com/axhDTefB).